# Class variable alternative for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We need to find a good place to store page metrics as a rails page loads. It'll include stats,  initially how many times certain slow methods are used. We're using a class variable on ApplicationController at the moment but that seems like code smell. Is there a better way to do this?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  cattr_accessor :page_stats

  def increment_slow_stuff()
    @@page_stats ||= {}
    @@page_stats[:slow_stuff] ||= 0
    @@page_stats[:slow_stuff]  += 1
  end

  def slow_method()
    increment_slow_stuff()
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an instance variable? If you later need to store it for longer, you could always save a record at the end of the pageview. Plus, a PageStats model would let you do more advanced analysis of your metrics.

Comment: This turned out to be the way to go. What I was forgetting was that the rails `controller` is easily accessible from the view. No need for globals.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this method of doing it is that the stats will only be around as long as the class is. I would recommend writing to  a database or maybe even Redis.

You could also subscribe to these events so that the code isn't inside your controllers using the technique shown in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3)

Comment: Was just writing the same answer about the using ActiveSupport::Notifications. To me, that's definitely the way to go. It nicely decouples your stats collection.

Comment: Thanks. I neglected to mention that I only need the metrics around for single page. We'll output these stats in a footer that only site admins will see. ActiveSupport::Notifications looks promising. Upon further searching, rails-footnotes looks like it might be an option.